# Mixing React with Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a React based application, running off a NodeJS based server, and would like to allow it to download a non-static file, without the use of xhr.

I am thinking of using Express, but I am not sure how I would make it co-exist with React in the same container? Can anyone suggest how I would go about this? I am still learning webpack and React, and I having trouble finding examples of this?

The React server is started via webpack:

```
node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8081 --hot --inline
```

With the webpack-dev-server.js, looking as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

The './src/index.js' is React type code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I've never used `webpack-dev-server` extensively myself (at least not directly), but I can think of two solutions.

One is to use `setup` in the `webpack-dev-server` configuration. As [stated here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#api):

```
setup: function(app) {
  // Here you can access the Express app object and add your own custom middleware to it.
  // For example, to define custom handlers for some paths:
  // app.get('/some/path', function(req, res) {
  //   res.json({ custom: 'response' });
  // });
}
```

Alternatively, which is a method I use myself, is to use [`webpack-dev-middleware`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware), which is a middleware for Express. So basically, you create your own Express server that has the same functionality as `webpack-dev-server`.

Here's an excerpt from one of my projects (where `app` is the Express app instance):

```
// Webpack (only when not running in `production` mode):
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  debug('setting up webpack middleware');
  const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
  const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
  const webpackConfig        = require('./webpack.dev');
  const compiler             = require('webpack')(webpackConfig);

  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    noInfo     : true,
    publicPath : webpackConfig.output.publicPath
  }));
  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. BTW I see indication that I should be able to use React without needing npm, but I can't see how to create the distribution bundle from webpack. Any ideas?

Comment: @AndreM see [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html#individual-downloads) (although I would probably always use npm/Webpack when building React apps, because it makes it so much easier to manage configuration and install additional requirements).

Comment: I have just seen that I can use webpack to package and then I just need to copy the bundle.js and non-React resources. To package: ```node node_modules/.bin/webpack ``` and then the rest is just a matter of copying. I can then just use express traditionally and serve the React stuff as if they were static files.

Comment: @AndreM yeah that's basically how you use Webpack in production: bundle the assets and serve them as static files =D

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @robertklep's answer, based on some further research, you can 'compile' your React project and then just make use of those resources without nodejs.

Use node & webpack to 'compile' your project:

```
node node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

This will create a bundle.js file which contains the compiled project. Other files, such as the images, external Javascript and stylesheets will need to be copied, for example (assuming there is a dist folder):

```
cp bundle.js dist/
cp index.html dist/
cp -rf img css frameworks dist/
```

Everything in the dist folder then can be served via a traditional web server, such as Nginx or Apache, with NodeJS.